# How to convert digit to word in Crystal Report 8.5

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008, crystal-reports-8.5

Hi i need to convert any digit to word using Crystal Report 8.5. However i tried the function ToWords( , ) to convert but it is not what i required.

My requirement is that to convert

```
Example: 1001 --- One zero zero one
```

Please help me how do i implement that way.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There is no built-in conversion for this. You can use this formula to convert the number to text:

```
ProperCase( ToWords({numberField}, 0) )
```

But that will give you "Onethousandone" in your case. If you want each digit spelled out, you will need to do the above for each digit of your numberfield.

EDIT: Here is an example of how you could get the first digit of your number:

```
shared stringvar wholeNumber;
shared stringvar firstDigit;
shared numbervar digit1;

wholeNumber = cStr({numberField});
firstDigit = left(wholeNumber,1);
digit1 = toNumber(digit1);
ProperCase( ToWords(digit1, 0) )
```

In your case this would spell "One". To get all your numbers you would have to create a formula for each digit.

Comment: I know that formula. But how do i spelled out one by one digit as given in the example. I am confused.